# What am I seeing on my terminal when I am running npm start?

Tags: angular, npm

I have a small question. When I am running npm start on angular2, what am I seeing on my terminal? Where it comes from?
I mean:

```
[1] Did not detect a `bs-config.json` or `bs-config.js` override file. Using lite-server defaults...
[1] ** browser-sync config **
[1] { injectChanges: false,
[1]   files: [ './**/*.{html,htm,css,js}' ],
[1]   watchOptions: { ignored: 'node_modules' },
[1]   server: { baseDir: './', middleware: [ [Function], [Function] ] } }
[1] [BS] Access URLs:
[1]  --------------------------------------
[1]        Local: http://localhost:3000
[1]     External: http://10.243.111.72:3000
[1]  --------------------------------------
[1]           UI: http://localhost:3001
[1]  UI External: http://10.243.111.72:3001
[1]  --------------------------------------
[1] [BS] Serving files from: ./
[1] [BS] Watching files...
[1] 16.10.25 13:16:35 200 GET /index.html
[1] 16.10.25 13:16:35 304 GET /node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js
[1] 16.10.25 13:16:35 304 GET /node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js
[1] 16.10.25 13:16:35 304 GET /node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js
[1] 16.10.25 13:16:35 304 GET /node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js
[1] 16.10.25 13:16:35 200 GET /styles.css
```

Thanks for answers!

Comment: Which part of the output do you not understand?

Comment: I assume you are using angular-fullstack generator, seeing express running on 3000.  You should have browsersync with the welcome page open, once that you have gotten here.  Do you mind spelling out your issue?

Comment: i think its related to this [issue](https://github.com/johnpapa/lite-server/issues/41)

Comment: I am just trying to understand where these lines come from and what does it mean. What does mean [0] and [1] in the beginning of each line

Comment: I was trying to find the source of all this in the project but it is not there. So, the question is what is the source

Comment: The `[0]` and `[1]` identify which process the output is coming from - it's part of the [concurrently](https://github.com/kimmobrunfeldt/concurrently) package, which the Angular 2 tutorial recommends using so you can have your TypeScript compiler and the development server running simultaneously with one command. So in the output you posted, `[1]` corresponds to `lite-server`, and presumably `[0]` would correspond to `tsc`.

Answer (score 0):

That output is from [`lite-server`](https://github.com/johnpapa/lite-server), which is a port of [`browser-sync`](https://browsersync.io/). Both are used in local development.

It's showing you configuration, URLs it provides and list of files your app is requesting...

Comment: Thanks. It looks like that's it

Answer (score 0):

I have searched it. These are compiled files. The compiler compile ts files immediately. And we see these compiled files